# Redirecting SubDomain To A Custom Address

Tags: cname-record

I need some help because I'm new in this thing so please.

I bought a domain from BigRock and I hosted it on blogger so I want to redirect my subdomain to a link.

I mean any link like my fb profile so I don't know how to do this so help me. I know how to create a subdomain but I dont know how to redirect it to any custom URL.

For example I want to redirect fb.domain.com to fb.com/page

Answer (score 1):

That would need to be handled via a 301 or 302 redirect on your web server.

Comment: Surely you mean 301/302?

Comment: Yep, it's been a long day.